# simPRO API for Log In issue

Tags: objective-c, api

I want to create a mobile app for simPRO software. For this reason I have to know the default API of simPRO for LogIn Issue.
Now I want to know what is the API and what are the parameters I have to pass???

Answer (score 0):

Each customer of simPRO gets their own URL to access their software therefore to write an integration you will need the user to first enter their URL.  The API for that build is then accessed via http://buildaddress/api.  Documentation on the API can be found at api.simpro.co.

We can also set you up with access to our sandbox site so you can test your integration.  If you would like this please send and email to support@simpro.co asking for sandbox api access and we will get these details to you.

Hope this helps and please let me know if you have any further questions regarding simPRO integration.